# solve a third order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve this PDE?

$$\partial_t(\frac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}-u_{xx})=K$$ where $c$ and $k$ are constants.

I was thinking to substitute $\psi=u_t$, so that the PDE becomes a wave equation. But then I get stuck because it is not homogeneous...

Answer (score 1):

A particular solution to $c^{-2}\psi_{tt}-\psi_{xx}=K$ is $\psi(x,t)=-Kx^2/2$.